# Ajax call in wordpress not working for subscriber user

Tags: ajax, wpdb

All

In my application there is notification system, when user click on that icon I want to make ajax call.
The problem id it works fine for admin user (Debug : 200 ok), but not for subscriber user (Debug : 301 moved permanently).

Ajax call

```
$("#notifications-button").click(function() {


    $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',

    url: '<?php echo get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' ?>',
    data:'action=my_special_ajax_call&value=1',
    success : function(data){
        $('.message-count').hide();
    },

    });
});
```

Function

```
 function implement_ajax() {

if(isset($_POST['value']))
  {

    global $wpdb, $user_ID;

    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_frm_items SET alerts_flag = 0 WHERE user_id = '". (int)$user_ID ."'" ));
}
}
add_action('wp_ajax_my_special_ajax_call', 'implement_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_special_ajax_call', 'implement_ajax');//for users that are not logged in.
```

I do not able to get why this not working for subscriber?
Is there anything wrong in code?

Thanks In Advance !

Comment: Show your code that you use to localize the script.

Comment: I am not making any kind of separation for specifc user , i just wanted to work this for all

Comment: Not a solution to your question but it would be better to use `admin_url('admin-ajax.php')` rather than `get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'.`

Comment: You're asking here _as YOU don't know further_ and maybe _WE know more_. So please... think about if it _maybe_ has a reason...

Comment: Do you have something like Role Scoper installed?... I've had problems with AJAX and Role Scoper before now.

Comment: @StephenHarris yes i am using Role Scoper

Comment: @AjayPatel And why did it then work for admin users? URis are the same for everyone...

Comment: @kaiser i am sorry still its not working

Comment: I agree with Kaiser. That shouldn't have solved it. You might want to check again...

Comment: @AjayPatel Please join us in chat...

Comment: Disable Role Scoper.

Comment: @StephenHarris i tried admin_url('admin-ajax.php') this but same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is a conflict with the plug-in *Role Scoper*. Deactivating the plug-in resolves the issue. As an alternative to Role Scoper, (I do not offer this as a *recommendation*, simply a suggestion), there is the plug-in [Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/).

Answer (score 0):

Solving by make manual ajax call to test.php page

```
<?php 

ini_set('html_errors', 0);
define('SHORTINIT', true);

require '../../../wp-load.php';
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/formatting.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/meta.php' );
require( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/post.php' );
wp_plugin_directory_constants();

// stuff goes here

if(isset($_POST['value']))
  { 

    $uid=$_POST['value'];
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE wp_frm_items SET alerts_flag = 0 WHERE user_id = $uid" ));
}
?>
```

Comment: You'll want to do some nonce checks (and perhaps permission checks), and also, look up how to use [`$wpdb->prepare`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks). Right now the above would leave your database open to attack.